# Glue Ray Script Logging/Print stdout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm noticing that on my AWS Glue Ray jobs, I see print statements in the logs for the jobs that fail, but those same print statements do not show up in the same logs when the job is successful.

Looking at Cloudwatch group:  /aws-glue/ray/jobs/script-log

I can go back and see output from jobs that fail up to the point in teh script where it fails. But, for a job that is marked successful, no such print statements exist.

Bug?